# How can I correctly push back a series of objects in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++

The scope of the program is to create a Container object which stores in a vector Class objects. Then I want to print, starting from a precise Class object of the vector all its predecessors.

```
class Class{
public:
    Class(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            Class c;
            c.setName(i);
            if (i > 0) {
                c.setNext(_vec,i-1);
            }
            _vec.push_back(c);
        }
    }   
};
    ~Class();
    void setName(const int& n);
    void setNext( vector<Class>& vec, const int& pos);
    Class* getNext();
    string getName();
    void printAllNext(){ //print all next Class objects including himself
        cout << _name <<endl;
        if (_next != nullptr) {
            (*_next).printAllNext();
        }
    }
private:
    Class* _next;
    string _name;
};

class Container{
public:
    Container(){
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
               Class c;
               c.setName(i);
               if (i > 0) {
                   c.setNext(_vec,i-1);
               }
         _vec.push_back(c);
    };
    ~Container();
    void printFromVec(const int& n){//print all objects of _vec starting from n;
    _vec[n].printAllNext();
    }; 
private:
    vector<Class> _vec;
};

int main() {

    Container c;
    c.printFromVec(5);
}
```

**The problem is that all _next pointers of Class objects are undefined or random.**
I think the problem is with this part of code:

```
class Container{
public:
    Container(){
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
               Class c;
               c.setName(i);
               if (i > 0) {
                   c.setNext(_vec,i-1);
               }
         _vec.push_back(c);
    };
```

Debugging I noticed that pointers of already created objects change their values.
**What is the problem? How can I make it work?**

Comment: Looks like some wrong copy-and-paste, `Class` constructor is going into infinite recursion.

Comment: When you add elements to a vector, the underlying storage may be reallocated to make room for more objects. This invalidates any pointers that you have. In fact, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) mentions just this. Why do you need the `next` pointer if you’re storing the objects in a vector?

Comment: It really doesn’t look like the `next` pointer is needed at all. You could take advantage of the full capabilities of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) such as iterators.

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile (mismatched braces). Present the _actual_ [mcve] you used to reproduce the problem, not some made-up thing.

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to set `next_` to something? If you never set it to something, you should *expect* it to contain random data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is really error in the code (likely wrong copypaste), the problem is really following: `std::vector` maintains inside dynamically allocated array of objects. It starts with certain initial size. When you push to vector, it fills entries of array. When all entries are filled but you attempt pushing more elements, vector allocates bigger chunk of memory and moves or copies (whichever you element data type supports) objects to a new memory location. That's why address of object changes.

Now some words on what to do.

Solution 1. Use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`. `std::list` is double linked list, and element, once added to list, will be part of list item and will not change its address, there is no reallocation.

Solution 2. Use vector of shared pointers. In this case you will need to allocate each  object dynamically and put address into shared pointer object, you can do both at once by using function `std::make_shared()`. Then you push shared pointer to vector, and store `std::weak_ptr` as pointer to previous/next one.

Solution 3. If you know maximum number of elements in vector you may ever have, you can leave all as is, but do one extra thing before pushing very first time - call `reserve()` on vector with max number of elements as parameters. Vector will allocate array of that size and keep it until it is filled and more space needed. But since you allocated maximum possible size you expect to ever have, reallocation should never happen, and so addresses of objects will remain same.

Choose whichever solution you think fits most for your needs.

Comment: Or leave the container as it is but just drop the whole `next` thing as being completely superfluous. Intrusive linked lists are not necessary when you already have each node in a container.

Answer (score 1):

**@ivan.ukr** Offered a number of solutions for keeping the pointers stable. However, I believe that is the wrong problem to solve.

- Why do we need stable pointers? So that `Class` objects can point to the previous object in a container.
- Why do we need the pointers to previous? So we can iterate backwards.

That’s the **real** problem: iterating backwards from a point in the container. The `_next` pointer is an incomplete solution to the real problem which is iteration.

If you want to iterate a vector, use iterators. You can read about them on the [cppreference page for std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I don’t want to write the code for you but I’ll give you some hints.

- To get an iterator referring to the `i`th element, use `auto iter = _vec.begin() + i;`.
- To print the object that this iterator refers to, use `iter->print()` (you’ll have to rename `printAllNext` to `print` and have it just print this object).
- To move an iterator backwards, use `--iter`.
- To check if an iterator refers to the first element, use `iter == _vec.begin()`.

You could improve this further by using reverse iterators but I’ll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I know iterators would be a better solution for this problem but it was just a semplification of my real problem (creating a BST with objects of a vector).